# How do I learn the exact version of my Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

How do I learn the exact version of my Windows 10 installation, including build number, revision number and branch such as `1203.5544 insider / technical -  preview / full`.

I went to startup and it says about bitness (64 bit) of Windows 10 and not any other information.

Last night I was sleeping while it was updating from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Now its installation is complete, and I need to know which version exactly, so I can further complete any necessary actions to unlock full version if it isn't already opened yet.

All it says on top is `Windows 10 Home`.

I think I was started with "insider", but now it doesn't write anywhere.
What do I do if it's still insider?

Comment: Open CMD and type in `systeminfo` check near the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to find the build / version of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/963910/how-to-find-the-build-version-of-windows-10)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this web page that probably has the answer to your question, *[Windows 10 update history](http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/)*:

> If you just want to find the OS name, you can use ver command. Just
>   open command window and execute ver command. But note that this does
>   not show service pack version.
>
> ```
> C:\>ver
> Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
> C:\>
> ```
>
> As you can see above, ver command just tells you the OS name but not
>   the service pack number you are using. We can find service pack number
>   as well as the OS name using Systeminfo command. But Systeminfo dumps
>   lot of other information also. So we need to use findstr command to
>   filter out unwanted information.
>
> ```
> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
> ```

Comment: It writes 10.0.10240 thank you. I can accept in 3 mins. Do you know which category is this version by the way?

Comment: Probably the stable release, it's the same version I have, and I'm not on insider builds.

Comment: Then I can start coding with this immediately not have to do anything in the future?

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Run menu by pressing the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> together.

In the Run window, type `winver`.

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Version 10.0 and bild 10240 it says similar to other answers here (with styles)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using the Windows 10 Cortana Search Function

1. Press the <kbd>**Windows Key**</kbd> once
2. Start typing "**about**"
3. Press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

The Edition, Version, and OS Build will be listed:
[image]

[image]