# How do I find out what the latest available version of Windows 10 is?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Sometimes I have a computer that claims it has all the latest updates, but I don't believe it (I'm not sure if updates are working right). I see that [I can look up what Version of Windows 10 that machine is running](https://superuser.com/questions/963910/how-to-find-the-build-version-of-windows-10), but how do I know if that version is the latest? Is this information listed somewhere?

Comment: Please remember that for major updates such as Windows 10 Version 1607 (a.k.a. the Anniversary Update), Microsoft will typically stagger the release over the course of several weeks (or months).  As a result, an operating system may claim that it is up-to-date based upon having the latest build number for that version.  For example, when version 1607 was released last August the machines with the latest build of version 1511 would say they were up-to-date until the staggered Windows Update major release cycle flagged that machine.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, @Run5k. I'm worried about machines that are potentially much further behind than that (e.g., that have been factory restored but report being up to date after suspiciously few updates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find that Microsoft maintains web pages that show the latest Windows 10 versions and build numbers:

[Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825/windows-10-update-history)

[Windows 10 Release Information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx)

Within those references, you can see that the latest version of the current branch for Windows 10 is version 1607, build number 14393.576.